# Named Pipe file on Windows 7

Tags: windows, wireshark, tshark

At the moment I'm successfully running the following tshark command on Windows 10 and Windows server 2012:

```
tshark -l -n -r "\\.\pipe\tsharkpipe2"
```

but when I run it on Windows 7 and Windows server 2012, tshark gives me `File does not exist error`. However I can use the pipe with `-i` like:

```
tshark -i "\\.\pipe\tsharkpipe2"
```

but I need to run `-Y` filter and `-T pdml` which seems cannot be done using `-i`.

I'm using tshark 2.0.5 and [C# Example](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=WiresharkSender.cs) from [Wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes) and both tshark and my client are running as Administrator.

Am I missing something here?